# Remove Category from List in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have looked all over for a fix for this but I can't find one that works.

I have this code:

```
            <?php 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'dining' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

    $dining = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $dining[] = $term->name;
        
        
    }

    $dining = implode(", ", $dining );
    ?>


            <div><b>Open For:</b> <?php echo $dining; ?> </div>
```

I have a custom post type with it's own custom categories. I want to remove one category from the displayed list. It currently displays like this:

Open For: Category 1, Category 2, Category 3, Category 4

I want to remove Category 2 from this list. How do I do that? I have searched all over but none of the results seem to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't push it into the `$dining` array, like this:

```
$dining = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if(!$term->name == 'Category 2'){
        $dining[] = $term->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
$list_ignore_categories = array( 'Category 2', 'Else Category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if ( in_array( $term->name , $list_ignore_categories ) ) {
       continue;
    }
    $dining[] = $term->name;
}
```